# USB won't boot in UEFI mode on HP Elitebook

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub, uefi, hp

I was trying to install Arch Linux on an HP Elitebook 840 G1, but find
that, since the usb doesn't boot in UEFI mode, I can't install grub.
I've tried changing the boot option to /Native UEFI/ rather than /Hybrid
UEFI/.  If I do that, the USB just doesn't show up.  I've factory reset
all the firmware settings and am using the newest firmware.  How do I
make the installation-USB boot in UEFI mode?

I was surprised that this problem was not mentioned on the Arch-Wiki
page for 840 G1.  Might this be a problem with the newer Arch ISOs?

(I also tried installing Legacy GRUB.  This appeared to work, but the
installation wouldn't boot.  Firmware said no OS was found.)

Comment: Have you tried using Rufus and writing the image in UEFI-only mode? That possibly could change things

Comment: May I suggest not using Grub in the first place? Systemd-boot is so much simpler. See the Arch Linux wiki for instructions.

Comment: +1 for avoiding Rufus and other loomy stuff like that, try just dd'ing the image or reading through official instructions.  There's one more caveat I'm aware of: some firmwares ignore shim with *two* signatures.  As a media variation, you can also dd ISO from http://en.altlinux.org/rescue and try booting that -- if it boots, then at least you know something can, and it's easier to dig further :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use option Customized Path to have default UEFI boot for this laptop.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HP_EliteBook_840_G1

For ubuntu i set Customized Path in BIOS to `\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and it finally worked.